# regsvr32 doesn't work on my winXP admin account

Tags: windows, windows-xp, regsvr32

**Summary**

`regsvr32` fails with code 0x80004005 (E_FAIL - Unspecified failure) on my admin account, but works on Administrator account.

Previously I didn't have this problem.

**Full question**

Recently, I have noticed some problem on my PC:

- I couldn't install PowerChute v3

  According to the [FAQ](http://www.schneider-electric.us/sites/us/en/support/faq/faq_main.page?page=content&id=FA159740), the fix was

  ```
  regsvr32 vbscript.dll
  ```

  However, running that on my admin account failed with this error

  > DllRegisterServer in vbscript.dll failed.
  >   Return code was: 0x80004005

  According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 0x80004005 is means "E_FAIL - Unspecified failure".

  Surprisingly, it worked when I ran `regsvr32` as Administrator account.
- "Edit with Notepad++" entry in context menu  disappeared.

  Thanks to [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/249d4d40), I found that the solution was

  ```
  regsvr32 NppShell_06.dll
  ```

  Similarly, it also failed with error 0x80004005 on my admin account, but worked on Administrator account.

  Now, each time I install a Notepad++ update, I lose the context menu entry (unless I install the update as Administrator). This didn't happen some time ago.
- I couldn't install my HP printer network drivers.

  HP installer didn't give any error code.

  After several attempts, I thought the cause could be `regsvr32`.

  So I tried running the installer as Administrator, and it worked.
- My APC UPS is not always recognized.

  When I boot my PC, the device manager shows a warning and says

  > This device cannot start. (Code 10)

  Sometimes it works if I unplug and replug the usb wire, or if I disable and enable the device, or if I reinstall the driver. But most times it doesn't work.

  However, it always works on another computer.

  I suspect the problem is also `regsvr32`.

How can I make `regsvr32` work again?

Comment: Probably your user profile has something wrong. Try to create another admin account and try with that.

Comment: @maudam I created another admin account and it works.

Comment: Well, sometimes profiles get corrupted by improperly shutdown, virus/malware, etc etc. A new profile often solve this kind of issues. Now you have to move all your stuff from old profile to new one (docs, pictures, mail, etc) but i think it's worth. Using a partially corrupted profile isn't good.